# QueryableCollectionView with datagrid and dataform - selection changed issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I have an mvvm solution. In my `viewModel` I have an `QueryableCollectionView` of the class `BaseClass` objects and an standalone `BaseClass` element(let's call it seletedElem).

The `BaseClass` have a private `QueryableCollection` of the `ChildClass` objects - `SCollection`, and a property that returns this collection. Both classes are implementing the following interfaces:  `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `IDataErrorInfo`, `IEditableObject`. In my view I have `raddatagrid` which `itemssource` is binded to the `ObservableCollection` of `BaseClass` objects from `viewModel` and selected item is binded to the standalone `BaseClass` object - `selectedElem`.

The Dataform is binded to the currently selected grid item in this way :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=xxx,Path=DataContext.seletedElem.SCollection}"
```

Then before the first DataGrid's selection changed event, or after the new item is inserted to the grid, when I press add button of the `raddataform` the current item of the `SCollection` is always an empty item of type `ChildClass`, but after the grid's selection changed event(when one of the existing items is selected) the current item of the `SCollection` is always null and I'm unable to edit it's properties.

The `dataGrid` and `dataform` are Telerik components.

Is there anyway to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I have found two workarounds how to handle with this situation, but they are not solving the root issue. I will type them here, they may be useful for someone.

1st Copy the `QueryableCollection` SCollection direct to he view 
    `ViewModel` and then is case events like  grid's `SelectionChanged` or DataForm's
    `CommitEdit`,`EndEdit`, `CancelEdit` just set the SCollection of the selected "BaseClass" 
     `instance` to the current SCollection from the `ViewModel`

2nd Use the `AddingNewItem`,`EditEnded`,`DeletingItem` `DataForm` methods to support yor
    own operations logic esspecialy CRUD and validation operations. So for example in 
    `AddingNewItem` add manually empty ChildClass instance to the selected object
     SCollection collecion - code sample :

```
public void OnAddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            ChildClass item = new ChildClass();
            var queryable = SelectedBaseObject.SCollection.OfType<ChildClass>().ToList();

            queryable.Add(item);

            SelectedBaseObject.SCollection = new QueryableCollectionView(new ObservableCollection<ChildClass>(queryable));


            ((RadDataForm) sender).BeginEdit();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```